# How can i resolved memory issue in parse api in android?

Tags: android, memory

**ERROR**

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer   AbstractStringBuilder.java, line 94
java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0     AbstractStringBuilder.java, line 124
java.lang.StringBuilder.append  StringBuilder.java, line 271
java.io.BufferedReader.readLine     BufferedReader.java, line 417
com.parse.ParseCommand.sendRequest  ParseCommand.java, line 399
com.parse.ParseCommand.perform  ParseCommand.java, line 331
com.parse.ParseQuery.findFromNetwork    ParseQuery.java, line 483
com.parse.ParseQuery.access$200     ParseQuery.java, line 79
com.parse.ParseQuery$2.runOnNetwork     ParseQuery.java, line 381
com.parse.ParseQuery$2.runOnNetwork     ParseQuery.java, line 379
com.parse.ParseQuery.runCommandWithPolicy   ParseQuery.java, line 338
com.parse.ParseQuery.findWithCachePolicy    ParseQuery.java, line 388
com.parse.ParseQuery.find   ParseQuery.java, line 427
com.parse.ParseQuery.find   ParseQuery.java, line 417
nightflyer.us.MainActivity$Splash_Async.doInBackground  
        MainActivity.java, line 291     
        nightflyer.us.MainActivity$Splash_Async.doInBackground  
        MainActivity.java, line 1
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call     AsyncTask.java, line 287
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run     FutureTask.java, line 234
... 3 more
```

Comment: show the code which caused the error

Comment: give the code otherwise it is meaningless